# What happened to JDic? Any replacement project?

Tags: java, deployment, file-association, jdic

I'd always heard of the JDic project being around, but never really had a need for it until now (I'm looking to register file associations with Java, and it seemed like the most promising solution.)

However, upon going to its [project page](http://java.net/projects/jdic/) (the only one I can find) it seems that there's no jar downloads or anything of the sort, and the last commit was over a year ago (the last series of "active looking" commits was over 3 years ago!)

I'm presuming this is now a dead project - is this the case? And if so is there any replacement? Or has it just moved (I certainly couldn't find where to though?) It'd be nice to just be able to grab the jars from somewhere rather than build the whole lot from source. Failing that, is there a better option (or what's the next best option) for registering custom file types using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Sun Developer Network article, [Using the Desktop API in Java SE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/desktop-api-142259.html), still links to JDic (Desktop API being a more restricted, read-only subset).

Seems like Eclipse SWT [does not have support](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/program/package-summary.html) for editing file associations either, so I'm afraid you will be restricted to either finding a cached copy of jdic.jar or building it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking to register file associations

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can do that.  Does the app. have a GUI?

Here is a small [demo. of the JNLP API files services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) that declares an interest in the `.zzz` file extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it does have a GUI but if possible I'd like to avoid Java web start, at present I'm using izpack to give me a normal "installer" like feel. This is purely to do with the fact it feels more like what end users expect rather than for any technical reason.